# Cómo corregir este ejercicio en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo JAVA y realice el siguiente ejercicio, sin embargo fue calificado como incorrecto.

1. Estructura de una clase, la clase deberá llamarse: Reto
2. Crea un método llamado suma que reciba dos parámetros de tipo “int” llamados: valor1 y valor2, donde
   esos dos valores se sumen y el método devuelva la siguiente cadena: El resultado es: (a esto
   concatenarle el resultado de la operación).
3. Crea el método main.
4. Crea una instancia de la clase en el método main.
5. Manda a llamar el método desde el main con los siguientes parámetros: 10 y 5, luego imprime el
   resultado en consola.

Mi respuesta fue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las observaciones de mi instructor fueron:

- Método suma debe devolver una cadena de caracteres y no imprimir el resultado ahí mismo
- Método main debe instanciar una variable de tipo reto y realizar la suma de 10 y 5 a través del método de la variable para imprimir a pantalla.

Me pueden apoyar, por favor, como es la respuesta correcta.

Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok mira esta es tu respuesta:

1.- Primero creamos la clase

```java
public class Reto{
}
```

2.- Creacion del método

```java
public class Reto{
  //Te pide que retorne un String con la suma de los números
  public String suma(int num1, int num2){
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return "El resultado es: " + result;
  }
}
```

3.- Creacion del método main

```java
public class Reto{
  //Te pide que retorne un String con la suma de los números
  public String suma(int num1, int num2){
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return "El resultado es: " + result;
  }
  //creación del método main
  public static void main(String[] arg){
  }
}
```

4.- Creación de la instancia en el método main

```java
public class Reto{
  //Te pide que retorne un String con la suma de los números
  public String suma(int num1, int num2){
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return "El resultado es: " + result;
  }
  //creación del método main
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    Reto reto = new Reto();//probablemente genere un error por que no tiene contructor
  }
  public Reto(){//creación del método constructor para evitar algún error
  }
}
```

5.- Imprimir el resultado

```java
public class Reto{
  //Te pide que retorne un String con la suma de los números
  public String suma(int num1, int num2){
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return "El resultado es: " + result;
  }
  //creación del método main
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    Reto reto = new Reto();
    System.out.println(reto.suma(10,5));
  }
  public Reto(){
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El método no esta devolviendo una cadena como quiere tu profesor, estas imprimiendo el resultado desde el método. Eso lo solucionas de esta forma:

```
public static String suma (int valor1, int valor2){
   int resultado = valor1 + valor2;
   return "El resultado es: " + resultado;
}
```

Y en el método `main` llamas a este método dentro de un `System.out.println()`

Por otro lado te dice que crees una instancia de la clase Reto, y has utilizado los métodos estáticos. Por lo tanto no puedes hacerlo. El método debería de ser así:

```
public String suma (int valor1, int valor2){
   int resultado = valor1 + valor2;
   return "El resultado es: " + resultado;
}
```

Y en en la clase `main`, creas una instancia de la clase Reto:

```
Reto nombre_objeto = new Reto();

nombre_objeto.suma(5,10);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Reto{
public String suma(int valor1, int valor2){
int result = valor1 + valor2;
return "El resultado es: " + result;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
Reto valor_suma = new Reto();
System.out.println(valor_suma.suma(10,5));
}
public Reto(){
}
}
```

Tenía el mismo problema, espero y sirva, saludos.

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).Ademas este codigo es exactamente el mismo que el de la respuesta aceptada... que le agrega a la misma?